# how can i do the following on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, embed

I want such that if anyone click a link then on that page only (in which the person clicked link)another page should open as an embeded page or a i frame. how can I do this on my website using html or javascript ?

Comment: play with CSS(position,z-index etc) [http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this but im not sure it works.
**[JSFiddle - link](http://jsfiddle.net/bXj68/5/)**

**EDIT:**
**Html**

```
<body>
  <div id="box">
     <a href="javascript:show();" >Link</a>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">    
     <iframe src="" id="frame" width=100% height=100%></iframe>
     <div id="close"><input type="button" onclick="closeIframe()" value="X" /></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function show()
{
  box= document.getElementById("box");
  box.style.visibility="hidden";

  frame=document.getElementById("box2");
  frame.style.visibility="visible"; 
}
function closeIframe()
{
  box2=document.getElementById("box2");
  box2.style.visibility="hidden";
  box= document.getElementById("box");
  box.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

**CSS**

```
#box
{  
   background-color:yellow;
}
#box2
{
   position:absolute;
   top:7px; //here i've set 7px but you cant set what you want 
   visibility:hidden;
}
#close
{
   position:relative;
   left:100%;
   width:50px;
   top:-160px;
 }
```

Comment: it has worked but i want the iframe to fit to the full page how can i do that ? and after the i frame appears can the remaining content of the page be removed (except iframe ) ?

Comment: the iframe is loading as soon as the page is loaded, i want such that it will only be loaded after clicking the link

Comment: but if you cant see it because it is invisible, there are problems? you can make a div box that contains all but not the iframe. so if you want to show only iframe set the div to hidden

Comment: and why you want an iframe that should fit the full page?

Comment: can u tell me how can i do it ? (that div to hidden)

Comment: now i try and then i let you see

Comment: ok u try and then tell me

Comment: no i can't use button only link

Comment: EDITED: watch in my answer

Comment: it worked thanks, a general question can i add a close button to i frame ?

Comment: yes you can if you mean into the iframe.. PS if you want to do a favor to me, accept my answer if it is ok for you

Comment: tell me how can i add a close button to that iframe ?

Comment: i want to accept ur  answer but how can i do that , am new here. tell me how to add a close button to iframe?

Comment: if you want a close button like, for example the windows close button, you need to put a div near the iframe that onclick, it will hides the div container of the iframe... the close button can be a <button>? or a link? or a div?

Comment: the close button can be a <button> or a link , tell me how i can add the close button to the iframe

Comment: now i cant. when i can i try it.

Comment: ok now i did it. check the first link in my answer. for the positioning of the button you can do how you want. this is an example

Comment: can i use this single javascript for 8 frames ?

Comment: mmh yes. but you must change the id's. try

Comment: can u tell me how can i use the single javascript for 2 iframe

Comment: you need only to make another link if you want 2 links. if not use the same link but you need to add the document.getElementById in the function show(). just try man it is easy